# How to validate user input with database?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I am doing validating of user input with the database, check whether the input key in the textbox field is there a similar data in the database if there is it will prompt it, i doing in window form C#

I try before using a web method to validate it, but now i have a problem to transfer it to the form.class....basically i want to  check the name is it exist in the database if it does it will prompt

```
public Boolean validateName(String txtName)
{
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
                               Catalog=Staff;Integrated Security=True");
 SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand();
 dbCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StaffDirectory WHERE StaffName='" 
                                           + txtName + "'";
 dbCommand.Connection = conn;
 conn.Open();
 int matchesCount = int.Parse(dbCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

 conn.Close();
 return matchesCount != 0;
}
```

Comment: you should really learn how to handle database calls and connections, how to parse db results checking for null and so on...

Comment: @Abdul is how am i going to use change this web method to a function or way i can check whether there is simliar database once i click on the databse

Comment: @Davide Piras...i not very sure and i only  try before using web method and call the web method ......i never do before calling a check in the class directly

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is that you shouldn't let the DB handle this. It should have a transaction and if it works then everything is okay, otherwise it does nothing. All your parsing of input values should be handled in your code so that you do not force the DB to work more than needed.

Here's a [link](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/10/14/2515.aspx) that helps you gettings started with transactions

Comment: The code that he has provided doesn't depict that DB is handling something.

Comment: @Muqtadir I agree with that, but the text implies that he tries to validate data by using the DB.

Comment: @Marthin...so how? what should use ? or how should i do?

Comment: @cutexxxpies If I understand you correctly, your are either trying a) to check that a name is valid to insert into your DB or b) you are checking if the name is already in the DB. If im right about this then please tell in more detail exactly what your are trying to do accomplish, a or b.

Comment: @Marthin ...i doing the B) check whether the name exist or not it will do a else statment which is insert...which i have done...but the problem is i don't know how to check if name exist

Comment: @Marthin do you get what i mean

Answer (score 0):

Validation should be done at the Form logic. Don't transfer it to the database to handle. L

Follow this example of validation model in your UI code:

```
  protected void textBox1_Validating (object sender,
   System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      int x = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
      errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Not an integer value.");
   }
}
```

Comment: the code you do does it check whether the database has the data ? if it has it should prompt it...and the check should be done at button is it

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use prepared queries. It will avoid sql injection. Your code is not secure.
Here is an example from the [MS site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)